# SSH.Net Async file download

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sftp, ssh.net

I am trying to download files asynchronously from an SFTP-server using SSH.NET. If I do it synchronously, it works fine but when I do it async, I get empty files. This is my code:

```
var port = 22;
string host = "localhost";
string username = "user";
string password = "password";
string localPath = @"C:\temp";

using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    var files = client.ListDirectory("");

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {                        
        using (var saveFile = File.OpenWrite(localPath + "\\" + file.Name))
        {
            //sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName,saveFile); <-- This works fine
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginDownloadFile(file.FullName, saveFile), client.EndDownloadFile));
        }                        
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    client.Disconnect();

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `saveFile` is declared in a `using` block, it is closed right after you start the task, so the download can't complete. Actually, I'm surprised you're not getting an exception.

You could extract the code to download to a separate method like this:

```
var port = 22;
string host = "localhost";
string username = "user";
string password = "password";
string localPath = @"C:\temp";

using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    var files = client.ListDirectory("");

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {                        
        tasks.Add(DownloadFileAsync(file.FullName, localPath + "\\" + file.Name));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    client.Disconnect();

}

...

async Task DownloadFileAsync(string source, string destination)
{
    using (var saveFile = File.OpenWrite(destination))
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginDownloadFile(source, saveFile), client.EndDownloadFile);
        await task;
    }
}
```

This way, the file isn't closed before you finish downloading the file.

---

Looking at the SSH.NET source code, it looks like the async version of `DownloadFile` isn't using "real" async IO (using IO completion port), but instead just executes the download in a new thread. So there's no real advantage in using `BeginDownloadFile`/`EndDownloadFile`; you might as well use `DownloadFile` in a thread that you create yourself:

```
Task DownloadFileAsync(string source, string destination)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var saveFile = File.OpenWrite(destination))
        {
            client.DownloadFile(source, saveFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I still get the same empty files when I try this. No exception either.

Comment: @spersson, I updated my answer. Looks like there is no advantage in using `BeginDownloadFile`, so you might as well use the synchronous version.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I guess I'll use the synchronous version then :)

Comment: Though it is a bummer that they don't use IO completion ports in their implementation, the advantage to using the `Begin*` async overloads over creating your own thread is that some of their IAsyncResult implementations expose a cancellation mechanism, should you need to halt transfers midway through. I wrapped BeginUploadFile in an extension method to make things feel more modern. Check it out: https://gist.github.com/ronnieoverby/438034b19531e6272f98

Answer (score 0):

They finally updated the methods a while back but didn't add explicit `DownloadFileAsync` as was originally requested. You can see the discussion here:

https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/pull/819

Where the solution provided is:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Add functionality to <see cref="SftpClient"/>
/// </summary>
public static class SftpClientExtensions
{
    private const int BufferSize = 81920;

    public static async Task DownloadFileAsync(this SftpClient sftpClient, string path, Stream output, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await using Stream remoteStream = await sftpClient.OpenAsync(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await remoteStream.CopyToAsync(output, BufferSize, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public static async Task UploadFileAsync(this SftpClient sftpClient, Stream input, string path, FileMode createMode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await using Stream remoteStream = await sftpClient.OpenAsync(path, createMode, FileAccess.Write, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await input.CopyToAsync(remoteStream, BufferSize, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```