# How to abort an Action from SftpClient class' DownloadFile() function (SSH.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) to implement downloading of a file via secure `SSH/SFTP` connection. I need also to be able to see the progress of the download and to be able to abort it if a user wants it. So the code looks like this:

```
ConnectionInfo conn = new PasswordConnectionInfo(host, port, username, password);
SftpClient sshSFTP = new SftpClient(conn);
sshSFTP.Connect();

try
{
    FileStream streamFile = File.Create(strLocalFilePath);

    sshSFTP.DownloadFile(strFilePath, streamFile,
        (ulong uiProcessedSize) =>
        {
            //Callback
            processProgress(uiProcessedSize);

            if(didUserAbortDownload())
            {
                //Aborted
                throw new Exception("Aborted by the user");
            }
        });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download failed: " + ex.Message);
}

streamFile.Close();
sshSFTP.Disconnect();
```

I couldn't find any documented way to abort the `Action` callback function for the `DownloadFile` method, so I resorted to throwing an exception.

But the problem with such approach is that my custom exception is not caught.

Any idea how to remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use their async (though [not true async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34039917/1062614)) flow, i.e. `BeginDownloadFile`. The `IAsyncResult` implementation returned by that method, [`SftpDownloadAsyncResult`](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/1711d5a3b5b87cb08a3341517322e5261123e228/src/Renci.SshNet/Sftp/SftpDownloadAsyncResult.cs), exposes cancellation through its `IsDownloadCanceled` property.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to put together a Method to report progress and handle cancellations for Renci SSH Uploads and Downloads using your tip here.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using asynchronous interface, as suggested by @ejohnson, you can also just close the output stream:

```
try
{
    FileStream streamFile = File.Create(strLocalFilePath);

    sshSFTP.DownloadFile(strFilePath, streamFile,
        (ulong uiProcessedSize) =>
        {
            //Callback
            processProgress(uiProcessedSize);

            if(didUserAbortDownload())
            {
                //Aborted
                streamFile.Close();
            }
        });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if(didUserAbortDownload())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Download cancelled");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Download failed: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```